Associating specific JSON schema version with YAML file in IDE/YAML editor
Context
We have a Java command-line application that can run 'actions', which are basically YAML files describing action parameters, steps to be executed, ...; somewhat similar to a GitHub Action workflow or other YAML-based CI/CD pipelines.
We provide a JSON schema (generated using jsonschema-generator) to offer code completion, property descriptions and validation to action developers in IDEs like VS Code or Eclipse.
Different users may be running different versions of our CLI application, so for example:

Application versions 2.0.0 and 2.1.0 may support schema version 1.0
Application version 2.2.0 may support schema versions 1.0 and 1.1
Application version 3.0.0 may support schema version 2.0 (potentially we could also provide backward compatibility with schema versions 1.0 and 1.1)

Primary requirement is ease of use for both action developers and application users, while ensuring correct behavior when mixing different application versions with different schema versions.
Our application doesn't do explicit schema validation; if the YAML-file can be deserialized successfully (and some internal checks pass), we consider it valid. However, we do want to validate that the YAML file uses a schema version that's supported by the current application version.
For example, potentially the meaning of a property could change between schema versions, i.e., someProperty is interpreted as a plain string in application version 2.0.0, but interpreted as some template expression (still represented as JSON string) in application version 3.0.0. Without explicit schema version check, the action developed for application version 3.0.0 (based on newer schema version) would potentially successfully deserialize on application version 2.0.0 but cause incorrect behavior.
Schema association in IDE/YAML Editor
Based on the research I've done, there seem to be 3 common approaches for (semi-)automatically associating a schema to a YAML file.
1. yaml-language-server comment
IDEs like VS Code and Eclipse, support a comment like the following:
# yaml-language-server: $schema=https://my.site/schemas/action/myapp-action-schema-1.0.json

However, comments are not deserialized by Jackson, so based on this comment alone, our application can't validate whether the YAML file is using a schema version that's supported by the current application version. I can think of two approaches to handle this, as listed in 1.a. and 1.b. below.
1.a. Manually parse comment
We could manually parse this comment from the YAML file, prior to Jackson deserialization. If the comment is not present, we'd reject the file. Potential advantage is that we don't try to deserialize YAML files that use an unsupported schema version.
1.b. Introduce required schemaVersion property
Instead of manually parsing the YAML comment, we could introduce a required schemaVersion property that should match the actual schema version being used. This puts additional burden on the action developer as they need to repeat the schema version; once in the yaml-language-server comment to enable IDE/editor validation & code completion, and once in the schemaVersion property to allow our application to validate whether it's a supported schema version.
2. $schema property
Some editors also allow for taking the schema URL from an explicit property, for example Eclipse Wild Web Developer plugin allows for configuring custom schema tags like $schema (which seems to be configured by default). However, contrary to some internet articles, my VS Code (using Red Hat YAML plugin) doesn't seem to automatically interpret this property as a schema location (any way to easily enable this?). Being a model property, this would allow our application to validate whether it's a supported schema version.
3. Glob-based matching
Another common approach seems to be based on file glob matching, for example we could post our schema to schemastore.org and have it automatically associated to our yaml files if we use a file naming convention like *.ourapp-action.yaml.
However, to support multiple schema versions, we'd likely need to have a compound schema that selects the appropriate schema version based on some property value, for example schemaVersion or maybe $schema (with the latter potentially hindering troubleshooting, as it may be unclear whether the editor/IDE loads the schema directly from the location specified in this this property, or through the glob-based compound schema association).
Maintaining such a compound schema adds some maintenance overhead, and this approach results in fairly long YAML file names to allow for a proper glob pattern.
Question
Which of the approaches above for associating YAML files would provide best user experience for action developers, allowing them to use the IDE/YAML editor of their choice, while still allowing for easy schema version validation by our application?
Or, in other words, which of yaml-language-server comment, $schema property or glob-based association is better supported by common YAML editors/IDE's?
Are there any best practices/conventions that may apply here? Any other considerations/pro's/cons of each approach, or alternative approaches that may work even better?
From an implementation perspective, approach 1.a. seems easiest, but potentially (also) adding support for approach 2 would allow for even more flexibility for action developers to use their IDE/editor and validation tools of choice. Approach 1.b. would be less preferred due to having to specify schema version twice.
Approach 3 seems more geared towards situations where only one schema version needs to be supported; less ideal for our purpose given the extra effort of creating and maintaining a multi-version compound schema. But maybe there are other advantages provided by this approach that outweigh the easier implementation of the other approaches?
Additional considerations
One potential complication with explicit $schema or schemaVersion properties is a mismatch between our Java model and JSON schema. Ideally, these properties should be constants in the JSON schema (matching the actual schema location/version), but from an application perspective, we'd need to be able to accept multiple values. For example, given the original example in the 'Context' section, application version 2.2.0 would accept either 1.0 or 1.1 schema versions.
From an application perspective, in our model we could have a SupportedSchemaVersion schemaVersion Java property, with `SupportedSchemaVersion being an enum like the following:
public enum SupportedSchemaVersion {
    @JsonProperty("1.1") current,
    @JsonProperty("1.0") V1_0;
}

However, by default, the generated schema would then also list schemaVersion as an enum, allowing both 1.1 and 1.0. Especially with approach 1.b. above, this would allow for action developers to use the 1.1 schema, but specify schemaVersion as 1.0, for example in an attempt to make this action compatible with older application versions that only support schema 1.0. The schema would however still allow 1.1-specific properties, thereby causing failures when trying to load the action in an older application version.
We can easily solve this by generating a custom property definition during schema generation, as we're already doing for some other properties/types. For reference and educational purposes, this is the code that we currently use for schema generation:
public class GenerateActionSchema {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        if ( args.length!=1 ) { throw new IllegalArgumentException("Output directory must be specified as single argument"); }
        var outputPath = Path.of(args[0]);
        SchemaGeneratorConfigBuilder configBuilder = new SchemaGeneratorConfigBuilder(SchemaVersion.DRAFT_2020_12, OptionPreset.PLAIN_JSON);
        JacksonModule jacksonModule = new JacksonModule(JacksonOption.RESPECT_JSONPROPERTY_REQUIRED, JacksonOption.FLATTENED_ENUMS_FROM_JSONPROPERTY);
        configBuilder.forTypesInGeneral().withCustomDefinitionProvider((type, context) -> {
            if (type.getErasedType() == TemplateExpression.class) {
                var custom = context.getGeneratorConfig().createObjectNode();
                custom.put(context.getKeyword(SchemaKeyword.TAG_FORMAT), "spelTemplateExpression")
                    .putArray(context.getKeyword(SchemaKeyword.TAG_TYPE))
                        .add(context.getKeyword(SchemaKeyword.TAG_TYPE_BOOLEAN))
                        .add(context.getKeyword(SchemaKeyword.TAG_TYPE_INTEGER))
                        .add(context.getKeyword(SchemaKeyword.TAG_TYPE_STRING))
                        .add(context.getKeyword(SchemaKeyword.TAG_TYPE_NUMBER));
                return new CustomDefinition(custom, true);
            } else if (type.getErasedType() == JsonNode.class ) {
                var custom = context.getGeneratorConfig().createObjectNode();
                custom.put(context.getKeyword(SchemaKeyword.TAG_ADDITIONAL_PROPERTIES), true)
                    .putArray(context.getKeyword(SchemaKeyword.TAG_TYPE))
                        .add(context.getKeyword(SchemaKeyword.TAG_TYPE_OBJECT))
                        .add(context.getKeyword(SchemaKeyword.TAG_TYPE_STRING));
                return new CustomDefinition(custom, true);
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        });
        SchemaGeneratorConfig config = configBuilder
                .with(jacksonModule)
                .with(Option.EXTRA_OPEN_API_FORMAT_VALUES)
                .with(Option.FLATTENED_ENUMS)
                .with(Option.FORBIDDEN_ADDITIONAL_PROPERTIES_BY_DEFAULT)
                .with(Option.MAP_VALUES_AS_ADDITIONAL_PROPERTIES)
                .build();
        SchemaGenerator generator = new SchemaGenerator(config);
        JsonNode jsonSchema = generator.generateSchema(Action.class);
        Files.createDirectories(outputPath);
        var outputFile = outputPath.resolve(String.format("ourapp-action-schema-%s.json", SupportedSchemaVersion.current.toString()));
        Files.writeString(outputFile, jsonSchema.toPrettyString(), StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.WRITE, StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING);
        System.out.println("Action schema written to "+outputFile.toString());
    }
}


Two many questions in a single question post. On Stack Overflow we expect a question to be focused on a single problem.

Thanks for the comment. Essentially it all comes down to the single problem of how to properly manage multiple versions of the same schema though. The multiple questions are mostly individual aspects of that single problem, focusing on different perspectives like how to model this in JSON schema, how to easily integrate with IDEs/editors, and how to manage this from the application & maintenance perspective. Honestly I don't see how I could have split this into separate posts, as all aspects are important considerations on how to properly solve this problem.

"single problem of how to properly manage multiple versions of the same schema though." - You are talking not about a problem but about a task, solving which implies solving multiple problems and answering many questions, some of which are mostly subjective. Like "should we simply accept any YAML file that can be successfully deserialized?".

Thanks for the feedback. Indeed many of the original questions were subjective; the various considerations I listed already answered why you might (not) want to take a particular approach, and ultimately we'd need to decide this ourselves. Main reason for asking these questions was to see whether I'd missed any considerations that could influence our decision. I've now rewritten my post to ask which approach allows for best IDE/editor support, which is ultimately what we're looking for. I did keep many of the considerations as they may be useful for others struggling with similar questions.
